# volatile variables or volatile structure problems in C

Tags: c, volatile

Here is my header file (Header.h)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void Process(void);
```

and "Header.C"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Header.h"

struct St{
    unsigned long int volatile Var1;
    unsigned long int volatile Var2;
    unsigned char volatile Flag;
};

extern struct ST Variable;

void Process(void){
Variable.Var1=Variable.Var2;
}
```

and Main file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Header.h"

struct St{
    unsigned long int volatile Var1;
    unsigned long int volatile Var2;
    unsigned char volatile Flag;
};

struct ST Variable;

//Interrupt each 10us

void TIM_IRQHandler(){

//Do something

    if(something==True)
    {
    Variable.Flag=1;
    Variable.Var2=AVariable; //AVariable is between 30-40
    }

}

int main(){

    while(1)
    {
    //wait 10ms
    if(Variable.Flag==1)
        {
        Process();
        Variable.Flag=0;
        }

    }

}
```

As you can see an Interrupt occurs each 10us and if it does some codes correctly it will change Var2 with a value between 30-40 and set a Flag variable. in Main code if Flag has been set it should be call process function and change Var1 with Var2 value.
But **sometimes** I receive var1 with other strange values that they are not correct.I have tested my interrupt and I find out I never fill my Var2 with strange values.

```
void TIM_IRQHandler(){

//Do something


    if(something==True)
    {
    Variable.Flag=1;
    Variable.Var2= < 30-40>;
    }
   if(Variable.Var2>40 || Variable.Var2<30){
      printf("ERROR");
     } 

}
```

and all Interrupt function works fine but in Process function it makes me angry.

I will appreciate for any tricks that I didn't pay attention.

Comment: What does this mean? `Variable.Var2= < 30-40>;` and how does it suppose to compile?

Comment: it is not my exact code but it means that it's value can something between 30 to 40

Comment: @Ehsan Zakeri: You have a potential race where a second interrupt fires and `Var2` while a previous result is still being processed. If the read is not atomic, say on a typical 8-bit MCU, then you may end up with some bytes from the previous value and some from the new. The easiest workaround for this is to reset `Variable.Flag` before `Process` and test so see whether it as gotten raised again afterwards, in which case you spin and try again. Conversely the flag should probably be of type `sig_atomic_t`, to this is unlikely to an issue in practice. And there are other gotchas to look out for.

Comment: @doynax Thanks for your explanation and contribution, I've had the same idea that it wants to process variable but in other process it wants to fill it up.I'm using Stm32f MCU (32bit) and unfortunately  this trick doesn't work. it is driving me crazy.

Comment: @Ehsan Zakeri: Fair enough, and the exceedingly short interrupt interval would tend to hit any subtle races which may be lurking. Unfortunately there too many gaps in the illustrative code to analyse it effectively. I would suggest that you try to narrow down a minimal yet complete reproducible example instead.

Comment: @doynax, Thanks for your contribution, Actually the main source code is more than 1000 lines and I'm sure that those code can make the problem harder. if there is no problem could you tell me access to a memory to read and wirte simultaneously can damage the data? or variable can't fill up well?

Comment: @doynax would it be possible to have your skype account to send source code and see the main structure?

Comment: @Ehsan Zakeri: I fear the first, and admittedly time-consuming, step is still for to go through and systematically pare down your codebase leaving only the bare essentials required to reproduce the problem. Effectively proving to yourself and us the parts the code which you think are irrelevant to the problem at hand truly have no bearing on it. If the process proves impossible due to an inability to reliably reproduce the fault or if any slight change masks the error then we discuss stray pointers and heisenbugs, but barring that creating a minimal repro case is still my first suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and your explanation , I will work better and if I can summarize the code much better I will tell you again , Thanks for everything

Answer (score 1):

Never expect anything when using the keyword "volatile" inside any kind of typedef. You are declaring the type "struct St", including the keyword. Your description implies that you expect a volatile behaviour on the variable "Variable", which is defined and declared without the keyword.
In my experience the keyword only sometimes (depending on platform and compiler) has an effect inside a type. It seems to reliably have an effect if used in both, the definition and the declaration of a variable.

Try changing

```
struct ST Variable;
```

to

```
volatile struct ST Variable;
```

and

```
extern struct ST Variable;
```

to

```
extern volatile struct ST Variable;
```

Also, is there a typo around "St" != "ST", with a "struct ST" type being declared elsewhere?
Also, as a side note, you might want to move your type declarations into the header.

I currently do not have access to a C environment, so please excuse me not testing my answer.

Comment: This answer refers to the effectiveness of volatile, considering it the relevant  part of the posted question; because of the title. Thoroughly protecting against racing conditions, as other have commented, is also very important to make this robust.

Comment: Do you happen to remember the compiler on which this failed? I have never had any issues with member-specific `volatile` (or `const`) qualifiers or qualifiers embedded into typedefs and as near as I can tell their use is supported by the standard, though I may be wrong and I certainly don't dispute that there are broken compilers out there.

Comment: Sorry for not being able to give some foundation for my statement. I have worked with several compilers, most of them cross compilers for embedded devices.  Concerning "const" on embedded devices:

Comment: On "const" on embedded:
It often links the constant objects into non-volatile memory and the non-constant objects into volatile memory.  
Which makes the declaration of struct members (being in close proximity in memory,  if not consecutive) with different "const/non-const" attributes inside a typedef very hard or inefficient to realise for the linker.
I cannot make this an argument for ineffective volatile keyword, but it makes it possible, if not likely.

Comment: I certainly agree that using `const` for ROM storage within a structure would be futile. The `volatile`/`restrict` qualifiers only describe access semantics instead of serving double-duty for data storage so I'm not sure the argument generalizes (I am unaware of any compiler shuffling volatile to special memory). Incidentally the reason I have used `const` structure fields in the past has been where dynamic data and read-only descriptors and have been intermingled within RAM for performance reasons (to avoid chase pointers) while documenting the intent not to modify the field.