# Passing a pointer to a struct with a volatile member as a function argument

Tags: c, pointers, struct, volatile

If I have a structure with some of the members being volatile but not all and I pass a pointer to this structure as a function argument, would the compiler prevent optimization to those members within the functions or do I have to declare the pointer as volatile as well?

```
typedef struct {
    volatile uint16_t reg1;
    volatile uint16_t reg2;
    const uint32_t speed;
    uint8_t error;
}uart;

void uartInitialize(uart *const hdlPtr);
//void uartInitialize(volatile uart *const hdlPtr); is this required?
```

Comment: Call it a superstition, but I do not believe in `volatile` keyword inside typdefs. I do not trust that all compilers behave the same with volatile inside typdefs. I only believe in it for complete variables and only at the definition of a variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [volatile variables or volatile structure problems in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42871877/volatile-variables-or-volatile-structure-problems-in-c)

Comment: I propose that duplicate, because the question does not show a volatile pointer (as described) but instead a const pointer to a volatile variable. In that constellation, it is a duplicate. Feel free to point out that you actually WANT a volatile pointer instead of the comment-deactivated code. In that case, I admit that it is NOT a duplicate. (*I trust in not having the dupe hammer here.*)

Comment: Considering to define an already `const` pointer (to a `volatile` variable) to be `volatile` in addition to `const` seems strange to me. Please double check whether that is what you actually want, because the commented code is not showing a volatile pointer, it is a const pointer to a volatile vairable, which happens to be what even I would trust - assuming that the variable pointed to was also defined volatile....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No need to add volatile on hdlPtr.

Long Answer: Unless the hdlPtr can be changed in some unexpected way, there is no need to declare it volatile. Given that it's being local to the function, it can not be changed by anything other than the uartInitialize. Given that you declared it 'const', it can not be changes by the uartInitialize itself.